# I can't get data from my Json file which contains small json files

Tags: json, node.js, rest, geojson, getjson

My problem is I have Json file of small json file creadted with node js 
I couldn't consume my json from that link and i tried to test my json file in some website like Json formatter there is this error : Multiple JSON root elements .
when i put only one json in json formatter it become right but like this example 2 json it it wrong
this is the example  of my json of 2 json ,

```
{"@timestamp":"2017-06-11T00:28:24.112Z","type_instance":"interrupt","plugin":"cpu","logdate":"2017-06-11T00:28:24.112Z","host":"node-2","@version":"1","collectd_type":"percent","value":0}
{"@timestamp":"2017-06-11T00:28:24.112Z","type_instance":"softirq","plugin":"cpu","logdate":"2017-06-11T00:28:24.112Z","host":"node-2","@version":"1","collectd_type":"percent","value":0}
```

Comment: What language do you want to use to work with this? Python? Node?
 Java? Please add a language tag. Whatever language you use, you'll need to break these objects apart, by splitting them on newlines, for example.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a json format json must have a root an object or an array

```
[
    {
        "@timestamp": "2017-06-11T00:28:24.112Z",
        "type_instance": "interrupt",
        "plugin": "cpu",
        "logdate": "2017-06-11T00:28:24.112Z",
        "host": "node-2",
        "@version": "1",
        "collectd_type": "percent",
        "value": 0
    },
    {
        "@timestamp": "2017-06-11T00:28:24.112Z",
        "type_instance": "softirq",
        "plugin": "cpu",
        "logdate": "2017-06-11T00:28:24.112Z",
        "host": "node-2",
        "@version": "1",
        "collectd_type": "percent",
        "value": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: You're right, of course, but this doesn't help the OP trying to deal with the data that he has.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file contents as a string, then split the lines and `JSON.parse` them one by one:

```js
const data =`{"a": 1}
{"b": 2}`;

const lines = data.split('\n')

const objects = lines.map(JSON.parse);

console.log(objects);
```